# Which generation of languages does SQL belong to?

Tags: sql, programming-languages

Is SQL classified as a [fourth generation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) or as a [fifth generation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth-generation_programming_language)?

Comment: The first link (which you have provided yourself, but apparently didn't look at) lists SQL as a fourth level language - it's in the "Database query languages" section. So why are you asking?

Comment: Does anyone still use the "N-generation" terminology? I haven't come across it since the 80s.

Comment: It depends if you use 0 as a first index, or 1 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tries to be a 5GL, by allowing the user to express their intent at a high level of abstraction while leaving the determination of an algorithm for achieving the intent up to the engine.

Unfortunately, due to various deficiencies in the language, it falls far short of that goal.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.  But does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. It is a query language, not a general purpose programming language.

Comment: But it can be [turing complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete/900062#900062).

Comment: @Primx - **Can** be. The answer you link even says that the SQL92 standard is not turing complete.