# Introduction to SQL for C++ programmer

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qtsql

I'm a C++ programmer who wants to expand his knowledge into SQL language because I'm dealing with QtSQL module and would like to understand it better.

I would like to find a gentle introduction to SQL language for a C/C++ programmer.
Can you suggest some reading or a particular tutorial?

Comment: Poor old Uncle Google misses you. You haven't visited him lately, do you?

Comment: As Panagiotis says, there's no difference in coming from C++ or not when you learn SQL. So loom for a good intro into SQL and in databases. SQL is not a programming language, it's a query language.

Comment: @Zane it is _used_ as a query language, but when suitably _abused_ it can serve far more inappropriate uses. See also, [SQL Turing Completeness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete) ;-)

Comment: @Rook: yep that's true for a lot of languages - but when you need to program, I prefer to use ROR over doing that in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982/looking-for-a-good-book-to-learn-sql

the highest rated answer recommends 2 nice books for beginners.

Coming from C++ field doesn't make much difference in this case in my oppinion. Start from basic stuff and you'll be fine!

For a nice web tutorial you can also check this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

**COMMENT**: You should not ask for recomendations in SO (although judging by your reputation you are aware of the rules). There are already various answers for this question as it is too generic and subjective. Read some books and tutorials and come back with SQL coding questions ;-)

Comment: Thank you @andrew and@Panagiotis Palladinos your answers are what I as looking for. I know google is out there, but I wanted an *opinion*. Seems that SO users are too lazy to give opinions and the common response is RTFM...

b.t.w I was pretty sure that this would have been downvoted...

Comment: SO users don't mind opinions but prefer to follow rules they developed themselves for this site.

Comment: Sometimes you are willing to "lose" some reputation in order to "fish" what you need. Personally I didn't mind your question that's why I answered. But as I stated in my comment I understand there is a solid reason behind every "rule". Especially rules that are built as democratically as the rules of SO.

Comment: Link to the question is broken