# Division of a field in mysql by comma

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+----+----------------------------+---------+----------+
| id | coordenadas                | latitud | longitud |
+----+----------------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | -50.23232323,-100.74329430 | NULL    | NULL     |
|  2 | 51.506944,-0.1275          | NULL    | NULL     |
|  3 | 19.433333                  | NULL    | NULL     |
+----+----------------------------+---------+----------
```

I use this query for separate the string by comma and insert into a new field:

```
UPDATE tabla SET
    -> latitud = SUBSTRING(coordenadas,1,LOCATE(",",coordenadas) - 1);
```

and works fine.

The problem is the ID:3. Only have a value and it´s not separated by comma. That value don`t insert into the new field (Latitud).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has the very convenient `substring_index()` function:

```
UPDATE tabla
    SET latitud = substring_index(coordenadas, ',', 1);
```

Longitude is a bit trickier.  Here is the code for that too:

```
UPDATE tabla
    SET latitud = substring_index(coordenadas, ',', 1),
        longitud = (case when coordenadata like '%,%'
                         then substring_index(coordenadas, ',', -1)
                    end);
```

This will set it to `NULL` for the third row.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not a programming language.

Use PHP or some other scripting language to make changes like this.

Comment: Is SQL or TSQL Turing Complete? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete