# Are mongodb aggregations turing complete?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Mongodb aggregation pipelines and the expressions available inside it make it look like a full language. However, I do not know how to test if a system is turing complete. Has anybody written/said anything about the turing completeness of mongodb aggregations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about this as well. Theoretically it seems like it could be turing complete, similar to how vanilla sql can be turing complete. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7580013/15314201

However, in practice the aggregation pipeline isn't meant for "scripting" but a rather a linear flow through the pipeline. Any sort of loops or functions or whatever would probably be better done in a language that interfaces with Mongo, such as using pymongo for the linear pipeline and python for more advanced control flows.