# How to mention jQuery on Resume?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was about to create my **RESUME**, and when i reached **Technical Expertise** portion I got confused about `where i should mention jQuery.`

So my question is simple, should it be mentioned under **LANGUAGE, TECHNOLOGIES,FRAMEWORK** etc??

Is it correct if i mention it under **Languages**???

And also is this correct  `•    Technologies :  HTML5 ,CSS3`    ?????

Sorry if it is not related question , but i guess it is **very important question** for me as it describes my RESUME.

Thanks :)

Comment: Jquery should comes under framework.. since it is created by using a scripting language called javascript.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy and HTML, CSS under technologies???

Comment: may be under languages.  as html is markup language and css is style sheet language

Comment: @MilindAnantwar So you mean HTML ans CSS should be under languages??

Comment: @Richa: yes they should be. and jquery under framework.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Just out of curiosity, If you or i asked the same question over here in SO, assume and tell me what would be the out come.? would it be 3upvotes or -300 downvotes.? :) :D

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: i would rather go with second one. plenty of downvotes :P

Comment: [is-html-considered-a-programming-language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145176/is-html-considered-a-programming-language)

Comment: @Richa Should be mentioned under Web Frameworks..
HTML5 is a language and JQuery is a framework.